# Using hoverFlow plugin with two animations

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm using the hoverflow plugin (http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/). It works wonderfully with one animation, but I'm trying to chain two animations together. In my jsFiddle, I want the title block to move to the left, then a description to fade in when you hover over with the mouse. The problem is when you move too quickly - the fade-in effect sticks instead of fading back out. I'm not great with jQuery; can someone take a look and help?

http://jsfiddle.net/corriespondent/yytwpurx/

HTML:

```
<div class="link">
<a href="#"><div><strong>Title</strong><span>Description</span></div></a>
</div>
<div class="link">
<a href="#"><div><strong>Title</strong><span>Description</span></div></a>
</div>
<div class="link">
<a href="#"><div><strong>Title</strong><span>Description</span></div></a>
</div>
<div class="link">
<a href="#"><div><strong>Title</strong><span>Description</span></div></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.link a { display: relative; display: block; width: 200px; height: 50px; background: #aaa; }
.link a strong, .link a span { display: block; }
.link a span { opacity: 0 }
.link a div { height: 50px; width: 100%;  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5); position: relative; margin-left: 35px; }
```

JS:

```
$(".link a").hover(
 function(){
  $("div",this).hoverFlow("mouseenter",{marginLeft: "0px"},"fast","swing",function(){
    $("span",this).stop().fadeTo("fast",1,"swing","");
  });
 },
 function(){
  $("span",this).stop().hoverFlow("mouseleave",{opacity:.001},"fast","swing",function(){
   $(this).parent().stop().animate({marginLeft: "65px"},"fast","swing","");
  });
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if this is what you are trying to achieve

```
$(".link a").hover(
    function(){
        $("div",this).animate({marginLeft: "0px"},"fast","swing",function(){});
        $("span",this).stop().animate({opacity:1},"fast","swing","");

    }, function(){
        $("div",this).animate({marginLeft: "35px"},"fast","swing",function(){});
        $("span",this).stop().animate({opacity:0},"fast","swing","");


});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yytwpurx/2/)